# @DirtiesConext not working

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have a suite of integration tests, all configured as:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = MyLoader.class, classes = {MyConfig.class})
@DirtiesContext
```

1 of my tests continually fails, complaining about the applicationContext state, throwing the message "Ensure that the context has not been closed programmatically"

As I have a brute force approach of assigning DirtiesContext to every test, really stumped as to what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try and implement a `classMode` and the `DirtiesContext` at the class level -

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode=ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
public class TestClass { .. 

@Test
public void test1(){ .. }
..

}
```

as mentioned in [Dirties Context JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html) so that the context will get closed once all the tests are executed.

> @DirtiesContext may be used as a class-level and method-level
>   annotation within the same class or class hierarchy. In such
>   scenarios, the ApplicationContext will be marked as dirty before or
>   after any such annotated method as well as before or after the current
>   test class, depending on the configured methodMode() and classMode().

Comment: What do you think context loader does here? And why do you think `@DirtiesContext` will have any effect on a custom loader?